# Javers Diff - Bug in JsonConverter - InitialValueChange

Tags: javers

I use JaVers 6.1.0 and want to create a diff of two objects with 'compare' and convert this to a JSON.

```
Diff diff = javers.compare(fooOldRevision, fooCurrent);
return javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(diff)
```

The output from this is:

```
{
  "changes": [
    {
      "changeType": "NewObject",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "cms.domain.Bar",
        "cdoId": "8519527a-0686-4297-bbae-7e1680f2bed8"
      }
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ObjectRemoved",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "cms.domain.Bar",
        "cdoId": "ffe90351-8d47-4a0e-ac4c-fdbd79573495"
      }
    },
    {
      "changeType": "InitialValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "cms.domain.Bar",
        "cdoId": "8519527a-0686-4297-bbae-7e1680f2bed8"
      },
      "property": "id",
      "propertyChangeType": "PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED"
    }
  ]
}
```

After that, I want to transform this JSON into a Diff again at another method with:

```
Diff diff = javers.getJsonConverter().fromJson(changes, Diff.class);
```

Normally, this does work without a problem.
If the diff includes a new Object (with the changeType "InitialValueChange") the second code snippet will fail with the error:

```
org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: MALFORMED_CHANGE_TYPE_FIELD: no such Change type - 'InitialValueChange'
```

Is there a fix I could use?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: duplicate to https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/1092

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now in https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/1092.